# Explicit expansion of the term $\overline{\psi}(i \gamma_\mu \partial^\mu-m) \psi$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation

Explicit expansion of the term $\overline{\psi}(i \gamma_\mu \partial^\mu-m) \psi$

In QED, one finds the first part of the Lagrangian density to be $\mathcal{L}=\overline{\psi}(i \gamma_\mu \partial^\mu-m) \psi
+\dots$

I am interested in expanding the term.

1. Am I correct to define $\psi$ as:

$$
\psi=\pmatrix{R_0+i C_0\\R_1+iC_1\\R_2+iC_2\\R_3+iC_3}
$$

where $R_0,R_1,R_2,R_3,C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3\in \mathbb{R}$.

2. Am I correct to define $\overline{\psi}=\psi^\dagger\gamma_0$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\psi^\dagger&=\pmatrix{R_0-i C_0 && R_1-iC_1 && R_2-iC_2&&R_3-iC_3}\pmatrix{0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0\\0&-i&0&0\\i&0&0&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{i(R_0-i C_0) && -i(R_1-iC_1) && i(R_2-iC_2) && -i(R_3-iC_3)}
\end{align}
$$

3. Am I correct to calculate the term $\overline{\psi}m\psi$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{\psi}m\psi&=m\pmatrix{i(R_0-i C_0) && -i(R_1-iC_1) && i(R_2-iC_2) && -i(R_3-iC_3)}\pmatrix{R_0+i C_0\\R_1+iC_1\\R_2+iC_2\\R_3+iC_3}\\
&={{m (C_0^2 + C_1^2 + C_2^2 + C_3^2 + R_0^2 + R_1^2 + R_2^2 + R_3^2)}}
\end{align}
$$

4. For the other term $\overline{\psi}(i \gamma_\mu \partial^\mu) \psi$, am I correct to write:

$$
\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_0 \partial \psi + \psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_1 \partial \psi + \psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_2 \partial \psi+\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_3 \partial \psi
$$

5. Then for each of the terms in (4), as:

$$
\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_0 \partial \psi = \psi^\dagger \partial \psi \\
= (dC_0 - i dR_0) (C_0 + i R_0) + (dC_1 - i dR_1) (C_1 + i R_1) + (dC_2 - 
    i dR_2) (C_2 + i R_2) + (dC_3 - i dR_3) (C_3 + i R_3)
$$

then

$$
\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_1 \partial \psi \\
= -(dC_3 - i dR_3) (C_0 + i R_0) - (dC_2 - i dR_2) (C_1 + i R_1) - (dC_1 - 
    i dR_1) (C_2 + i R_2) - (dC_0 - i dR_0) (C_3 + i R_3)
$$

then

$$
\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_2 \partial \psi  \\
= (dC_0 - i dR_0) (C_0 + i R_0) + (dC_1 - i dR_1) (C_1 + i R_1) - (dC_2 - 
    i dR_2) (C_2 + i R_2) - (dC_3 - i dR_3) (C_3 + i R_3)
$$

then

$$
\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma_2 \partial \psi  \\
= -(dC_2 - i dR_2) (C_0 + i R_0) + (dC_3 - i dR_3) (C_1 + i R_1) - (dC_0 - 
    i dR_0) (C_2 + i R_2) + (dC_1 - i dR_1) (C_3 + i R_3)
$$

6. Finally, adding everything together I get:

$$
2 C0 dC0 - C2 dC0 - C3 dC0 + 2 C1 dC1 - C2 dC1 + C3 dC1 - C0 dC2 - 
 C1 dC2 - C0 dC3 + C1 dC3 - 2 I C0 dR0 + I C2 dR0 + I C3 dR0 - 
 2 I C1 dR1 + I C2 dR1 - I C3 dR1 + I C0 dR2 + I C1 dR2 + I C0 dR3 - 
 I C1 dR3 + C0^2 m + C1^2 m + C2^2 m + C3^2 m + 2 I dC0 R0 - 
 I dC2 R0 - I dC3 R0 + 2 dR0 R0 - dR2 R0 - dR3 R0 + m R0^2 + 
 2 I dC1 R1 - I dC2 R1 + I dC3 R1 + 2 dR1 R1 - dR2 R1 + dR3 R1 + 
 m R1^2 - I dC0 R2 - I dC1 R2 - dR0 R2 - dR1 R2 + m R2^2 - I dC0 R3 + 
 I dC1 R3 - dR0 R3 + dR1 R3 + m R3^2
$$

---

edit:

A. Is this correct?

$$
\partial^t \psi=\pmatrix{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_0+i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}C_0\\\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_1+i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}C_1\\\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_2+i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}C_2\\\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R_3+i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}C_3}
$$

B.

Are the quantities $R_0,R_1,R_2,R_3,C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3$ then not the correct entries of matrix, but instead the entries should be functions $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{C}$:

$$
\psi=\pmatrix{ \psi_0[t,x,y,z] \\ \psi_1[t,x,y,z] \\ \psi_2[t,x,y,z] \\ \psi_3[t,x,y,z]}
$$

Comment: Paragraph 4 is wrong. You’ve lost the index on the partial derivative. I didn’t check the rest.

Comment: What is your motivation behind this expansion?

Comment: @JohnnyLongsom Same reason taking a TV apart and putting it back together makes it easy to understand how it works.

Comment: @G.Smith What does index means on the partial derivative (after I distributed the sum) ?

Comment: $\partial_0=\partial/\partial t$, $\partial_1=\partial/\partial x$, etc. You have to keep track of which coordinate the derivative is with respect to. There isn’t just one partial derivative; there are partial derivatives in various directions.

Comment: @G.Smith Can you have a look at question A. and B. of my edit (follow up of your expansion)?

Comment: A is correct if you are working in a $(1,-1,-1,-1)$ metric.

Comment: Regarding B, it’s OK to define $R_0$ and $C_0$ as real functions that are the real and imaginary parts of the complex function $\psi_0$, etc., but you have to let $\psi_0$, $R_0$, and $C_0$ be functions of $t$, $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go through it step by step. First note that we mean $\bar\psi (i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m )\psi = \bar\psi (i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m\mathbb{I} )\psi$ where $\mathbb I$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix. Let us calculate first the operator in the middle.

$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ is a matrix, after performing the contraction. We find:

$$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
 \partial_0 & 0 & \partial_3 & \partial_1 - i\partial_2\\ 
 0& \partial_0 & \partial_1 + i\partial_2 &  - \partial_3\\ 
 -\partial_3& -\partial_1 + i\partial_2 & - \partial_0  &0 \\ 
-\partial_1 - i\partial_2 & \partial_3 & 0 & -\partial_0
\end{pmatrix}$$

by treating the $\partial_\mu$ as each component being a scalar, times the matrices which are the components of $\gamma^\mu$. Explicitly we have taken $\sum_{i=0}^3 \gamma^i \partial_i$. Now we include the mass term, giving,

$$(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m\mathbb{I} ) = \begin{pmatrix}
 i\partial_0 -m& 0 & i\partial_3 & i\partial_1 +\partial_2\\ 
 0& i\partial_0 -m& i\partial_1 -\partial_2 &  - i\partial_3\\ 
 -i\partial_3& -i\partial_1 -\partial_2 & - i\partial_0 -m &0 \\ 
-i\partial_1 +\partial_2 & i\partial_3 & 0 & -i\partial_0 -m
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now we have $\psi = \begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c\\ 
d
\end{pmatrix}$ where each component is complex. We have that $\psi^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix}
a^* &b^*  & c^* & d^*
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\bar \psi = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$. Thus, to write the Dirac equation explicitly, first act on $\psi$ with the messy matrix we computed. Then you act on the resultant column with $\gamma^0$. Finally, you take the dot product with $\psi^\dagger$.